How do I modify replies to revisions with Google Drive API?
For Google Drive API, I know how to modify comments (comments.update, which requires fileID and commentID). I know how to modify replies to comments (replies.update, which requires fileID, commentID, and replyID).
But, how to I modify replies to revisions? What method do I use?
Revisions don't have a commentID; they have a revisionID, and I can't find anything in the Google Drive v3 API documentation regarding replies to revisions.
